# javascript onclick delete not working

Tags: php, javascript

Why is it that my onClick won't work?

When I click I get an error message like this:

```
syntax error : identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

It will not determine the ID from the database, the database ID is varchar(50).

```
<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick='delete_Affiliate(".$row['affiliateid'].")'></a>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function delete_Affiliate(id){
        alert(id);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
delete_Affiliate(" <?php echo $row['affiliateid']; ?>")
```

That is, you need to echo the value from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick="delete_Affiliate(<?php echo $row['affiliateid'] ?>)"></a>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function delete_Affiliate(id){
    alert(id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

there may be issue on this line
`<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick='delete_Affiliate(".$row['affiliateid'].")'></a>`
 it should be
 `<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick='delete_Affiliate("<?php echo $row['affiliateid']; ?>")'></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your PHP script ?
You should have something like :

```
<?php

echo "<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick='delete_Affiliate(\"".$row['affiliateid']."\");return false;'></a>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    function delete_Affiliate(id){
        alert(id);
    }
</script>";

?>
```

Comment: thanks man it really workssss thanks a lot got this code running right

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php 
 echo "<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick='delete_Affiliate(".$row['affiliateid'].");'></a>";
 ?>
```

or this :

```
<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick='delete_Affiliate("<?php echo $row['affiliateid'] ?>");'></a>
```

Comment: hi ive got error here i tried your code  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ralimo-rates-system\query\view_affiliate.php on line 49

Answer (score 0):

you have to add php tag and echo statement between your anchor tag like this

```
<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip'  onclick='delete_Affiliate("<?php echo $row['affiliateid']; ?>")'></a>
```

you didn't add this

```
<?php echo $row['affiliateid']; ?>
```

in your anchor tag so just add it and check it out.

I hope it will help you

Comment: Isn't that basically what the earlier answers said?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
delete_Affiliate(<?php echo $row['affiliateid']; ?>);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code, hope it will work

```
<a href='#' id='delete' title='Delete' class='icon-2 info-tooltip' onclick="delete_Affiliate(<?php echo $row['affiliateid'];?>);"></a>
```